# how much is the number of SMS sending with SMSManager?

Tags: android

I would like to know how much is the sending of an SMS via SMSManager? let me explain:
I have a list of several people and I make a FOREACH loop on their phone number.
The list contains more than 200 numbers

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after going through the Android sources for all the APIs supported by my app I cam up with the following code

> `private void setSmsDefaultLimitations(){

```
int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
String versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

switch(apiLevel){
case 9:
case 10:
case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
case 14:
case 15:
    sMaxAllowed = 100;
    sCheckPeriod = 3600000;
    break;
case 16:
    sMaxAllowed = 30;
    sCheckPeriod = 1800000;
    break;
case 17:
    sMaxAllowed = 30;
    if(versionRelease.contains("4.2.2")){
        sCheckPeriod = 60000;
    }else {
        sCheckPeriod = 1800000;
    }
    break;
case 18:
    sMaxAllowed = 30;
    sCheckPeriod = 60000;
    break;
default:
    sMaxAllowed = 30;
    sCheckPeriod = 1800000;
    break;
}
sMaxAllowed = sMaxAllowed - 2; //This is to give us a little buffer to be extra safe (like a condom ;)
Log.d(TAG, "maxAllowed = "+sMaxAllowed+"; checkPeriod = "+(sCheckPeriod/60000) + " minutes");
```

}`

Comment: I do not think we're talking about the same thing. I want to know if android limits the sending of SMS in mass.
If so, how much is this limit?